# Wrap form field

Tags: theming, forms

I want to render a form element like this:

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
  <label>Title: <span class="red">*</span></label> 
  <div class="pull-left">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hint hint--right" data-hint="Tooltip text goes here!!!"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried something like this:

```
$form['title']['#prefix'] = '<div class="form-group clearfix">';
$form['title']['#title'] = '<label>Title: </label>';
$form['title']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder'=> array('Title'));
$form['title']['#suffix'] = '<div class="pull-left"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hint hint--right" data-hint="Enter the title."></a></div></div>';
```

But it gives me:

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
  <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-title">
    <label for="edit-title">Title:  <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <input placeholder="Title" type="text" id="edit-title" name="title" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" class="form-text required uniqueness-processed">
  </div>
  <div class="pull-left">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hint hint--right" data-hint="Enter the title."></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So you see, there a basic structural difference after it is rendered by Drupal. What am I doing wrong? It will be better if I can manage the structure through form api only and dont have to create a template page for this form.

Any suggestions?

Comment: _It will be better if I can manage the structure through form api only and dont have to create a template page for this form._ I would disagree. You want to completely change markup Drupal provides, so it stands to reason you need to theme it. Whether that actually takes the form of a template file or theme function is irrelevant, but if you want to re-theme Drupal you need to use the theme system

Comment: Almost every form element is wrapped with `.form-item` or some common classes that you can use in both CSS and JS. If you are trying to integrate some javascript plugin to your site, I doubt you will ever need to wrap them again. Just make a clever use of the selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check it out this code:

```
$form['title']=array();
    $form['title']['#prefix'] = '<div class="form-group clearfix"> <label>Title: <span class="red">*</span></label><div class="pull-left">';
    $form['title']['#type']='textfield';
    $form['title']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder'=> array('Title'));
    $form['title']['#suffix'] = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hint hint--right" data-hint="Enter the title."></a></div></div>';
```

May this will help you

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks, just had to hide the original element title
`$form['title']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';`